# GZIP Compression Not Working with Parquet Data Format in AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, parquet, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate data from AWS RDS Postgres to S3. I need the data in s3 as compressed parquet format. I have selected the CompressionType as GZIP, but even after, the migration task creates .parquet files instead of .parquet.gz

[image]

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, parquet itself supports gz compression internally. If you look at the content of the `.parquet` file, is it referencing some sort of `.gz.parquet`? If yes, then actually it is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I have a same problem about the gzip with parquet when using DMS. Just look at the file. It is .parquet not .gz.parquet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).